# value of optional type 'String?'の対処法に関して

Tags: swift

```
value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

というSwiftのOptional型に関してのエラーが生じました。

Optional Value(「?」「!」が付随したコードで、「nil」を許容したコードか「nil」wo
許容しないコードのいずれかを明示する)にする必要があるのはわかったのですが、具体的に

```
let text = searchBar.text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

のコードのどこに対して行えば良いのかがわからないため質問致します。

以下コードなります。

```
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

private var results: [NSDictionary]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}


//中略


extension ListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

// searchBarのSearchボタンをタップしたときの処理
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder() // キーボードを閉じる

    // エラーはここから
    let text = searchBar.text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    //ここまでです。
    if let text = text {
        AFHTTPSessionManager().GET(
            "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(text)&country=JP&lang=ja_jp&media=music",
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
                if let data = response as? NSDictionary, results = data["results"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                    self.results = results
                    self.tableView.reloadData() // 再描画
                }
            },
            failure: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: 上記の問題は解決出来ました

Comment: 自分でも学習したのですが、何かご指導いただければ幸いです。


```
説明

Optional型はnilが代入されることを許容する変数の型を指します

Optional型=> 「?」「!」が付随されているコード

Optional型は「nil」を許容し、Optional Valueは「nil」を許容しない

AppleがObjective-CからSwiftに変更した理由の半分以上が、このOptional型にあると言っても言い過ぎでは無い。
なぜなら一般の変数はnilを許容せず、もし代入した値がnilだったら、プログラムエラーになり、アプリ全体が落ちてしまいます。
変数に対してnilを許容しないことは、プログラム内のバグが潜む場所を減らしていくということと同義です。


```